# Fat jar export from Eclipse error

Tags: java, jar, export, executable-jar

I'm trying to export a Java project from Eclipse. The project includes external libraries. I'm currently trying to use Fat Jar to package these libraries within the exported jar. I have specified the Main class in my manifest as well as the Fat Jar GUI. My Manifest looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0

Main-Class: com.selenium.test.TestPages
```

However, when I run

```
java -jar *name of jar*.jar
```

I get the error:

```
Error: An unexpected error occurred while trying to open file *name of jar*_fat.jar
```

Is there a way to get this running properly? Thank you.

Comment: Have you selected the _One Jar_ option?

Comment: maybe the content is in use, or protected, try to close eclipse if you do it implicitly

Comment: Thanks @jlordo I just tried with the One Jar option, and I made sure to close eclipse while trying to run the jar, but unfortunately I had the same result. Could it be a problem with my manifest (I am still figuring out manifests) or the particular libraries I am trying to include?

Comment: @SaraG: no need to close eclipse. Also, you don't have to fiddle with the manifest. Fat Jar will create it for you. You just have to select the correct main class in the Fat Jar exporter. Can you show some screenshots of what you are doing?

Comment: @jlordo I unchecked the "select Manifest file" and it worked! Some of the functionality that works when I run the program in eclipse is missing, but it's a good start, thank you very much.